Upgraded To Desktop 24.04 and now Settings and App Center Freeze up machine
Mine is an, admittedly, older machine. I upgraded today to 24.04 (Desktop) and have had problems with both Settings and the App Center. First, when either displays a popup, it is distorted and flickering. Second, sometimes, it just freezes. Now, most of the time I use the command line to add apps but the Settings situation is a pain.
Any ideas? Nothing has changed on the hardware size. It's a Latitude E6410 which has never had a problem with Ubuntu before.

There is also option of searching for your problem and fixing it yourself. My experience from being Windows admin was never upgrade to a new OS, because you take all the clutter and problems from the old one, boot the USB and try Ubuntu, if you have the same problems in try, then that version is not for you. If you do not get an answer within a couple of days (I imagine people are very busy), back up all that you want (not the programs) and wipe the partition clean, Then do a fresh install. If you keep GRUB be ready also to deal with problems that may come with it.

Searching didn't help. I'm not a noob, and I've seen this problem before, years ago with a Gnome update in Ubuntu. It eventually was fixed with an update.
